# How to reach my Raspberry Pi without having any possibility to connect it to the Internet?

Tags: networking, connection, raspberry-pi4

Hi stackoverflow community,

I made a little mistake to my raspberry Pi 4. I was connected via ssh and changed the /etc/network/interfaces file. Then i restarted the raspberry. Now i cannot connect to it because the interfaces file is broken. Also via lan, the raspberry isnt connecting to the network. Maybe somebody knows a way how i can get control of my raspberry now. Thank you for help.

Comment: put a monitor and a keyboard, login and change the interfaces files, restart the networking services and voila, you can connect via ssh.

Comment: @Vidal Thank you for answer. That would be a simple solution but now I overwritten my sd-card and its solved. I also havent got any micro hdmi to hdmi cable yet at home and have to buy one.